# inserting into a table where an index column has sequential values

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I have a table with a DATE column on it and I want to put an index on that column.  But I happen to know values in that column are assigned sequentially.  Mariadb uses B-trees by default, I think.  Is this going to be a problem?  Back in the old days this could create a "vine" in the index. and degrade performance.  We are writing queries `where date > (some date)`

EDIT - a vine is a degenerate tree structure. Imagine this binary tree where 1 is the root. It's a valid binary tree but because the values were inserted sequentially, there's no 'tree' only a 'vine'; a single line of nodes.

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> ...

Comment: I've never heard the term "vine" with respect to B-tree indexes. Can you provide a reference to this issue? I don't think sequential values will be any problem for the B-tree implementation in InnoDB, but I don't know for sure because I don't know what the "vine" issue is.

Comment: Updated with vine definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A B-tree is not a binary tree. B-trees are self-balancing (approximately). That is, all paths to leaf nodes tend to have the same length. Inserting a new entry, whether at the end or in the middle, will rebalance the tree automatically by the nature of the insertion algorithm. This includes splitting nonterminal nodes in the tree and shifting the tree to choose a new root node, so each child branch off the root has approximately equal subset of the tree.

If anything, inserting into a B-tree in sequential order *helps* to make the tree more compact and efficient. There's a good visualization of this advantage in this blog: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/03/illustrating-primary-key-models-in-innodb-and-their-impact-on-disk-usage/

Comment: Thank you. I knew there was no way that what I said could be how it works.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and MariaDB use B+Trees (see Wikipedia) for most indexes, including the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A B+Tree allows efficient sequential scanning because there is a link from one block to the "next".

The tree is a bunch of blocks containing (typically) about 100 rows.  (Row = data row or index row.)

When inserting, for example via `AUTO_INCREMENT`, into the "end" of the B+Tree, about 99 get added before a "block split" is required.  This split turns the one block into to, and adds an entry in their parent block, which slowly creeps toward being full.

Note that about 1% of INSERTs lead to a split.

The tree is rebalanced during *some* of those block splits.  The tree is kept balanced.  (I don't know the details.)  But it is infrequent enough that we should not worry about its cost.

Also, note that going from 1 million rows to 100 million rows adds only 1 level of BTree (from 3 to 4).  A Binary Tree with 100M nodes would be about 27 levels deep.